# How to pass form with sensitive data in php to external api

Tags: php, html

In my application i need to provide automatic transaction to my customer .I need to use api password for automatic otherwise it will be manual which i don't like.

```
<form method="post"action="https://api.sendmoney.com/">
<table>
    <input type="hidden" value="myapipassword" name="api_password">
        <tr><td>Amount</td><td><input type="text" name="AMOUNT"></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Receiver Email</td><td><input type="text" name="RECEIVEREMAIL"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sender mail</td><td><input type="text" name="SENDEREMAIL"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Whenever people submit above form The transaction is sucessfull.Problem is people can see my api password using view source . How to hide my api password.

Comment: post the values without the password to another php script which does a curl request to the api?

Comment: You need to make the request on your own server, for example with curl

Comment: Yes I suggest using a server-side language as a middle-man to communicate with the API (PHP, NodeJS, Ruby etc.) as @RamRaider suggested.